# Blur() event not firing in webkit browsers for select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit

I have a simple `<select>` element that has several `<option>` elements within:

```
<select id="dollarAmount">
    <option>select dollar amount</option>
    <option>$5</option>
    <option>$10</option>
    <option>$15</option>
    <option>$20</option>
</select>
```

This `<select>` form is only shown when the user mouses over another element on the page:

```
$("#parentDiv").mouseenter(function(){  
    $("#selectFormDiv").show();  //dollarAmount contained in this div
});
```

Upon triggering the `mouseleave` event on the `parentDiv`, I make sure the form is blurred so that the options do not remain expanded.  Once it is blurred, I can safely hide the containing `<div id="selectFormDiv">` so that the form and its container properly hide.

```
$("#parentDiv").mouseleave(function(){  
    $("#dollarAmount").blur();
    $("#selectFormDiv").hide();
});
```

My issue is: this works in IE8 and Firefox 5.1, but does not in Chrome 12.0 or Safari 5.1.  I've detected if the browser is a webkit and used different commands to test, and it just seems that `blur()` does not cause a `<select>` form to collapse (correct term? Attempting to hide the options that were dropped down).  The above code does not hide the options if they were expanded upon leaving the `parentDiv`.  Triggering the `hide()` event on the form does hide the options in Chrome (still no luck in Opera), but of course also causes the entire form to hide:

```
$("#parentDiv").mouseleave(function(){
    if($.browser.webkit) {
        $("#dollarAmount").hide();
        $("#selectFormDiv").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#dollarAmount").blur();     //blur only triggers for non webkits?
        $("#selectFormDiv").hide();
    }
});
```

I've tried several other events/methods, including [triggering document.mouseup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207929/is-there-a-dom-event-that-fires-when-an-html-select-element-is-closed/6688518#6688518) upon `mouseleave` to trigger a `blur()`.  I've attempted to use `focusout`, `change`, and `click` events to collapse the select form, but with no success.

Is there any way to hide a `<select>` form's `<option>`s in webkit browsers through an event call?

Edit: For clarity, the actual blur() event does seem to be triggering. I have the `dollarAmount` form listening for `onblur` just to print to the console.  The console print does execute, but the form is just not collapsed as it is in non webkit browsers when `blur()` is called.

Here's a fiddle to elaborate on the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JpWLb/4/
On non webkit browser:  Click the `<select>` element, but do not hover over any `<option>`s once they roll out.  With the options still expanded, mouse out of the containing div.  In firefox and IE, the resulting `$("#mySelect").blur()` call causes the options to retract (yay!).  However, on webkit browsers, blurring the expanded `<select>` element seems to do nothing: the options remain expanded.  My desired outcome is for all the browsers to hide the expanded options upon mousing out of the containing div.

Comment: have you tried setting focus on an invisible element rather then blurring the current one?

Comment: Did you try adding a fake <input type="text" /> and focus() it?

Comment: Good ideas.  I hadn't thought to do that.  I attempted to focus() a few different objects (fake objects, other select forms on the page, and the document itself) but I was never able to get the focused select form to blur.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. It appears that when the select element is activated in webkit, the DOM doesn't recognize any mouse events other than a click. So the problem isn't that your blur() method isn't firing. The problem is that the **mouseleave()** method isn't firing!

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JpWLb/

Open your console. When you move your mouse around, it will constantly get fed the string "ok". But as soon as you click on the select element, those console logs will cease.

Comment: Maxedison: Hmm, interesting.  I haven't been able to look this over with the proper respect it deserves (currently not at my machine with my project on it).  But I plan on thinking it through tomorrow morning and replying with some comments and possibly accepting answer.  Many thanks :)

Comment: Maxedison: I've looked at that fiddle from Chrome, IE, Firefox, and Safari.  Chrome and Safari both stop firing the 'mousemove' event when the mouse is inside the `<option>` elements.  IE also exhibits this behavior, but Firefox continues to fire the `mousemove` event, even inside the `<option>` elements.  Though this is true, it seems like I should still be able to detect a `mouseleave` on a parent div and trigger the `blur()` on the child `<select>` element.  I'll try to get a fiddle up in a bit.

Comment: Chrome & Safari are both webkit, so that explains their similar behavior. Given what I posted, I'm not sure why you say: "it seems like I should still be able to detect a mouseleave". As my fiddle shows, no mouse events are registering with the DOM at all it seems, other than a click. But I would love to see a solution... haven't had to worry about this problem yet myself, but I may someday :)

Comment: I'm attempting to detect a mouseleave on a parent `<div>` that is containing the `<select>` form, not the <select> form.  I've got a fiddle up now at the end of my original post that shows the setup I am using.  The code doesn't run perfect on non-webkits (mousing over an <option> also causes the form to retract) but elaborates on the issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: I understand that. But I'm saying that no DOM events other than a click fire on anything, parent divs, the active select element, etc.