# How to blur <SELECT> in 1 click when click another?

Tags: jquery, select, focus, blur

I can blur  `<SELECT>` when option selected by `.change()`

But how can I blur `<SELECT>` when `<SELECT>` open and click another element or `<BODY>` ?

Normally we have to click `<BODY>` 2 times to blur `<SELECT>` element right ?

How can I do only one click ?

```
$("select").focus(function () {
    $("code").html("focus");
}).blur(function () {
    $("code").html("blur");
});


$("select").change(function(){
    $("select").blur();
});
```

**Why I can't do like..**

```
$("*:not(select)").click(function(){
    $("select").blur();
});
```

I just only need to detect is `<SELECT>` open or close

**Demo :** http://jsbin.com/owitot/1/edit (try to open select box and click body)

Comment: On my system all you have to do to blur is to click something else, `select` included. It was my understanding that this behavior was more or less universal.

Comment: If you click another element, the select will close and therefore call the blur event. at least, that what happens on my machine. what os, browser etc are you using?

Comment: @WaleedKhan That's only the case for other `input` elements, doesn't appear to be the case for elements such as `<div>`, `<body>`, etc.

Comment: The first click closes the option list, the second removes the focus. Why do you want to change the behavior?

Comment: Firefox newest (Mac) / tested in all modern browsers , Just still same

Comment: @WaleedKhan If the select is opened at first you need to click somewhere else than the select element to close it, to unfocus it you need to click a second time.

Comment: for open/close `<select>` detection @Juhana

Comment: maybe I have to make my own custom select box :(

Comment: Why we can't do like `$("*:not(select)").click(function(){$("select").blur();});` ?

Comment: @l2aelba Might be worth taking a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it Not exactly the same, but the basic principle (detecting clicks outside of an element) is going to be the same.

Comment: Based on this and your previous questions, yes, it would probably be worth it to use a custom select field because you're really trying to twist the default into doing things it just won't do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the first click only closes the select element, it doesn't unfocus it. So to solve you problem, you should catch the close event and then do:

```
$("select").blur(); // This will even call your event listener!
```

But how to catch the close event? Unfortunately, there is no such (official) event. But perhaps this question helps: [Is there a DOM event that fires when an HTML select element is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207929/is-there-a-dom-event-that-fires-when-an-html-select-element-is-closed)