# Run function when a select option is selected twice in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a AJAX-loaded dropdown that runs a function when it's changed, but I also want it to run the function if the option that is already selected is clicked.  (For example, someone selects option A two times in a row, I want it to run the function both times without having to select a different option between them)

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).on('change','#dropdown',function(e){
  //do stuff
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="optionA">option A</option>
  <option value="optionB">option B</option>
  <option value="optionC">option C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You mean, run it if they open the drop down, and then close it without changing their choice?

Comment: Then the value isn't changing, so `change` is probably not the event you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a DOM event that fires when an HTML select element is closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207929/is-there-a-dom-event-that-fires-when-an-html-select-element-is-closed)

Comment: *I want it to run the function both times without having to select a different option between them* : Does this mean if user clicks the option first time function runs and other options are disable so that the user can only select the same option second time?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yes, but only if they click within the dropdown, not if they click outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of experimentation, but there is a way to detect if the dropdown menu of the select was clicked.

Move your code into the `click` event, and wrap an if tag around it as such:

```
if(event.pageY<0)
{
    // The dropdown menu on the select was clicked!
}
```

The reason that only this `if` is needed, is because of the fact that both browsers I've managed to test this on, make it seem like the cursor is outside of the actual page when the event was triggered.

You can find the demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Entoarox/ATm43/.

The `pageY` property of the event object is one of the properties that jQuery normalizes for cross-browser consistency.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Replace your on `change` script with:

```
$(document).on('click','#dropdown',function(event){
    if(event.pageY >= 0) return; // return and don't do anything 
    // The dropdown menu on the select was clicked!
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I took over your answer. There are numerous questions on SO about this idea but your answer is the only one I have seen that actually works. So I wanted it to be as complete as possible. Kudos.

Comment: Any reason for the DV here?

Comment: @iambriansreed Its not a problem, you simply expanded upon the rather basic information I provided, although my basic answer would solve the problem, adding details and mentioning that outside of jQuery the pageY value cannot be trusted absolutely is a good thing!

Comment: I like the idea, but it's not working for me in firefox or chrome on Mac.  The event fires, but it also fires when the dropdown is clicked to dropdown.

Comment: @GeoffreyBurdett Unfortunately as I dont have a mac, it is impossible for me to find out why it has different behaviour there. (What you can do is wrap a switch around the positioning check that forces it to only go off on the second click)

Comment: @GeoffreyBurdett I updated the demo fiddle to include the code to only trigger the check if the menu is open, please try http://jsfiddle.net/Entoarox/ATm43/3/ and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
$(document).on('select','#dropdown',function(e){
  //do stuff
}
```

or

```
$(document).on('click','#dropdown',function(e){
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: -1 `.select()` is for selecting text http://api.jquery.com/select/ `.click` fires before a value is set

Comment: My apologies, I was mistakenly referring to the jqxWidget, which fires a "select" event on thier' dropdown list.

Comment: ".click fires before a value is set" wouldn't matter in this example, as the value never needs to be set. It was indicated in the example that the drop down was meant to be clicked multiple times in succession.