# Fire onclick on <select> element but not on <option>

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, events, listener

My  element updates its options using the onclick() listener when clicked. The problem is the listener is firing when an option is clicked as well, so the user is unable to select anything in the updated list.

```
groupSelect.onclick = function() {
    PopulateList();
  }
```

I'd like to run my function only when the select element is clicked(when the menu has not dropped down yet) but not when a specific option is clicked. How can I do so? I'm writing the JS part using NodeJS.

Comment: Maybe try reading this post and checking out its fiddle. [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207929/is-there-a-dom-event-that-fires-when-an-html-select-element-is-closed)

Answer (score 0):

Events will bubble up the hierarchy, so a click on an `option` will also trigger any events bound to its parent `select`.

This is fixed by stopping propagation of the event on your `option` listener

```
$('option').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  //rest of code
})
```

Comment: This still fires the click event.

Comment: @RyanGill, no, it doesn't fire on the <select>.  http://jsfiddle.net/acozm48b/  This is the right answer.

Comment: @phari my console shows `(2) received click on select` when I select test2.

Comment: @RyanGill which browser are you using?

Comment: @phari I'm using Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 m

Comment: If it's not working, `stopImmediatePropagation()` might be a better option

Comment: @RyanGill, your link is giving me a 404, but I'll take your word for it that the code isn't working in your browser.  I'm using the same browser, same version (on a Mac, if that matters) and it's behaving correctly for me.  Apparently there is some deeper issue here.