# Triggering a function after select tag changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a select field with multi select option in which I need to trigger an ajax call after the select box closes(after selecting multiple options) at select box. Any help to implement this functionality.
`$('#selectBoxId').on 'change', ->
     $.ajax
         url: '/filter'
         dataType: 'script'`

I have code like this. This triggers ajax call on each select option. I don't use any plugin for multi select

Comment: Please provide an example of the markup you are working with.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Edited with sample code

Comment: Are you using bootstrap's multipleselection plugin?

Comment: Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207929/is-there-a-dom-event-that-fires-when-an-html-select-element-is-closed

Comment: @PatrickMoore I don't think that is the issue as the user says they have a multiselect.  A native multiselect does not "close".  So it's possible they are using a plugin, but that is unclear so far from the question.

Comment: @Taplar probably so. Tough to know without more information from OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by firing on `.blur()` rather than `.change()`, if you're using a native `<select multiple="multiple">` without plugin.

`.change()` event fires each time the value is changed. `.blur()` event fires only when the select element loses focus. But this event may not bubble down depending on whether you're using a third-party plugin or not.

Comment: I don't use any plugin

Comment: @Aarthi so can you try with `blur` rather than `change` and see if this accomplishes what you're after?