# How to listen to open and close events of a select on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, html-select

I am aware that no native events exist for `select` on open/close. I am using `select.mousedown` and `document.mouseup` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6688518), and they work well on desktop. However, they don't work as expected on mobile - when `select` is opened, **both** `select.mousedown` and `document.mouseup` fire, and when closed, **neither** fires.

Here's the code (and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8acm2y6u/)) - to reproduce the issue, open up devtools then device emulator (such as iPhone 6):

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select")

select.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  console.log('select mousedown')
})

document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  console.log('document mouseup')
})
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="1" data-label="One">1</option>
  <option value="2" data-label="Two">2</option>
  <option value="3" data-label="Three">3</option>
  <option value="4" data-label="Four">4</option>
</select>
```

I experimented with other events too trying to capture the moment when `select` is closed - `select.blur`, `document.click`, `select.mouseleave`, etc. - but **none** are firing on mobile. Here's a [more extensive jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/macryuo2/) - open up the device emulator, open the select box, and then close it (either clicking away or on the box itself) - no events fire.

I also tried to cover the page with an invisible overlay - the problem is either I can't seem to "trickle" the click event from the overlay down to `select` (I tried `document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).click()` inside `overlay.click`), or if I apply `pointer-events: none` then the overlay doesn't receive the click, only the `select` does.

Is there any way to listen to `select` open/close events on mobile? Thanks

Comment: Both `select mousedown` and `document mouseup` are logged when interacting with the select on an iPhone running iOS 15.2.1

Comment: @evolutionxbox Correct, that's half the problem. Also, neither fires when the `select` is closed. I can't find a single event that would fire on close.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no standard event for select open and close

one way is to build a custom dropdown, like one propose by bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events
with this one you have more event fired by the component when it is open or closed

- show.bs.dropdown : This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
- shown.bs.dropdown : This event is fired when the dropdown has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions, to complete).
- hide.bs.dropdown     : This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
- hidden.bs.dropdown : This event is fired when the dropdown has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions, to complete).

code come from the doc

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

$('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Comment: Building a custom dropdown is one option. I was hoping to get the native select working though

Comment: unfortunately i look for several solutions and the select native don't launch event when we leave him without change the value

Answer (score 0):

These are the events you need to achieve the desired behavior.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select")

select.addEventListener('focusin', e => {
  console.log('using select')
})

document.addEventListener('focusout', e => {
  console.log('no longer working on select')
})

document.addEventListener('change', e => {
  console.log('chose a value')
})
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="1" data-label="One">1</option>
  <option value="2" data-label="Two">2</option>
  <option value="3" data-label="Three">3</option>
  <option value="4" data-label="Four">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `focusin` works as expected, but `focusout` isn't suited for this. Ex: click on the select box then click away - the dropdown is closed but the focus remains on `select`, so `focusout` doesn't fire.

Comment: I'm assuming this issue is on mobile. Because on desktop it is firing on my side (Chrome)

Comment: I tried opening this snippet on my phone, and to get it to run, I used run as desktop, tapping away does trigger focusout

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention mobile. My original snippet works on desktop too. But on mobile, I'm not seeing any events fire.